# PhpStorm default git author

Tags: git, phpstorm

In PhpStorm I am having difficulty setting the default git author in the project settings:

I used the "Action finder" and searched through the settings, but I have not found this option.

Does anyone know where I can change this value, so I don't have to change it on every commit?

Comment: You were prevented from posting a video because we don't want users linking to videos. That should have been an indication that your question shouldn't include a link to a video. Don't cheat your way around Stack Overflow's rules.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Thanks to the information given by Andrew I was able to find a solution:

Go to your project folder \ .git \ config and add the lines below:

```
[user]
name = Your Name
email = name@domain.de
```

I hope this was helpful for other PhpStorm and git users.

Comment: I don't have such a file. Do I need to create it by hand?

Comment: @kwoxer: If you have a Git root in your project the ".git" folder should exist. The config file is essential, since the remotes are configured in there.

Comment: I cannot see it in PHPStorm because it's hidden, isn't it? Anyway I have set the name and email with the git command. No need for editing the file anymore :)

Comment: use your file explorer with "view hidden files" enabled to access the **.git** folder, or use the command line

Comment: Please take good note that .git is a directory the file to edit is config inside it, vi .git/config

Comment: This solution will change the author in the git repo, but if multiple dev' work on the same project, they would have to change the autor each time they commit/push something. Would it be possible for phpstorm to fetch the information about the user in the ~/.gitconfig file ?

Answer (score 22):

No clue on PhpStorm, but you should be able to do `git config user.name "Your Name"` and `git config user.email "Your email"` from a command line inside the repo and perhaps achieve the results you want.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Or let's say PHPStorm ignores that setting.